# MockServer verify with multiple body matchers

Tags: java, unit-testing, matcher, verify, mockserver

I'm using MockServer [body matchers](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/getting_started.html#request_body_matchers) to verify an endpoint request's body parameters. Some properties can be matched [exactly](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/getting_started.html#button_match_request_by_body_with_json_exactly), but others may need a separate [subString](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/creating_expectations.html#button_match_request_by_form_submission_body) or [regex](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/getting_started.html#button_match_request_by_regex_body) matcher, because part of that property is unknown. For example, a date-time string may have a known date, but unknown time.

However, with multiple `withBody()` calls, the `verify` method passes if one or more matcher passes. How to implement a logical AND instead of an OR?

```java
mockServer.verify(
    request()
        .withPath(url)
        .withMethod("POST")
        .withBody(
            json(
                "{\"firstName\": \"foo\",\"lastName\": \"bar\"}",
                MatchType.ONLY_MATCHING_FIELDS))
        .withBody(
            // Need subString because we don't know the time and only want to validate the date
            subString("\"order_date_time\": \"2021-04-15")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a logical-AND on multiple body matcher criteria, you need to call the `verify()` method multiple times:

```java
private void verifyOrderPlaced() {
  verifyName();
  verifyOrderDate();
}

private void verifyName() {
  mockServer.verify(
      request()
          .withPath(url)
          .withMethod("POST")
          .withBody(
              json(
                  "{\"firstName\": \"foo\",\"lastName\": \"bar\"}",
                  MatchType.ONLY_MATCHING_FIELDS)));
}

private void verifyOrderDate() {
  mockServer.verify(
      request()
          .withPath(url)
          .withMethod("POST")
          .withBody(
              subString("\"order_date_time\": \"2021-04-15")));
}
```